# Is there a trigger that ends Eileen's questline?

Tags: bloodborne

I'm at the last part of Eileen's questline where she lies in front of the Grand Cathedral and I have to fight the hunter inside.

If I continue playing without doing the fight right now, is there a trigger where  the fighter and Eileen will disappear (e.g. after a certain boss)? I want to complete the questline, but first I'd like to progress and level up more to fight the hunter. I just don't want to come back later and find that I missed my chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

There are a few triggers in the previous stages of the quest, but being on the last one you should be safe. And be careful not to kill her by mistake ; she can be killed by mobs, or if you use the *Choir Bell* on her.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? She will lie there for the rest of the game until I beat the last boss? Just checking because I couldn't find anything on that and don't want to risk anything.

Comment: Well, as usual, it's quite difficult to prove something *won't* happen. I haven't tried waiting until the last boss, but I didn't do it right away. And since various sources give all the ways to fail the quest *before* and don't state the possibility to fail it at this stage, aside from killing her...